# Diferenças entre RCurl, httr (R) e requests (python) ao fazer um POST

Tags: python, r, http, httr

Eu estava querendo acessar uma página que se obtém ao clicar em "Exibe todos os documentos acima" [nesse link](http://siteempresas.bovespa.com.br/consbov/ExibeTodosDocumentosCVM.asp?CNPJ=02.541.982/0001-54&CCVM=22551&TipoDoc=C&QtLinks=10). A empresa que eu peguei é só um exemplo, não tenho interesse nela.

Tentei resolver isso por meio de uma requisição POST, e consegui o resultado que queria usando a biblioteca `requests` do python. Código em python abaixo:

```
import requests
link = "http://siteempresas.bovespa.com.br/consbov/ExibeTodosDocumentosCVM.asp?CNPJ=02.541.982/0001-54&CCVM=22551&TipoDoc=C&QtLinks=10"
r = requests.get(link)
dados={'hdnCategoria':'0', 'hdnPagina':'', 'FechaI':'', 'FechaV':''}
r1 = requests.post(link, data=dados, cookies=r.cookies)
print r1.text
```

Tentei rodar os seguintes códigos no R, um usando `RCurl`:

```
library(RCurl)
link <- "http://siteempresas.bovespa.com.br/consbov/ExibeTodosDocumentosCVM.asp?CNPJ=02.541.982/0001-54&CCVM=22551&TipoDoc=C&QtLinks=10"
curl <- getCurlHandle()
r <- getURL(link, curl=curl)
r1 <- postForm(link, hdnCategoria='0', hdnPagina='', FechaI='', FechaV='', .encoding='UTF-8', curl=curl)
  cat(r1)
```

e outro usando `httr` (que pelo que sei é só um wrapper do `RCurl`):

```
library(httr)
link <- "http://siteempresas.bovespa.com.br/consbov/ExibeTodosDocumentosCVM.asp?CNPJ=02.541.982/0001-54&CCVM=22551&TipoDoc=C&QtLinks=10"
h <- handle(link)
dados=list(hdnCategoria='0', hdnPagina='', FechaI='', FechaV='')
r1 <- POST(handle=h, body=dados, encoding='UTF-8')
cat(content(r1, 'text'))
```

a) Por quê as duas alternativas em R retornam a página original e não o resultado de clicar em "Exibe todos os documentos acima"?

b) O que a biblioteca do python tem "a mais", que faz ela funcionar de forma tão simples?

PS: Para essa pergunta, não gostaria de usar `mechanize`, `selenium`, outras bibliotecas do python, etc. Queria resolver em R, preferencialmente com `httr` e, se não der, com `RCurl`. Existe também uma alternativa nova, o `rvest`, mas não conheço muito bem  e não sei se faz sentido usar nesse caso específico.

Comment: Não conheço R, mas pelo que eu entendi do seu código a principal diferença é que no exemplo em Python você está passando para o POST os cookies obtidos no primeiro GET, e nos demais códigos *me parece* que isso não está sendo feito. A importância disso é que muitos sites exigem que você passe um token secreto no POST para se proteger contra CSRF, ou alguma medida similar (não está óbvio pra mim o que esse site em particular está fazendo, mas o fato é que existem sim cookies com valores aleatórios sendo enviados na segunda requisição). Você precisa descobrir então como fazer isso em R.

Comment: Ignore o comentário anterior - mesmo após limpar os cookies no browser, ele ainda carrega a página normalmente. O problema não está aí...

Comment: @mgibsonbr aparentemente as funções que tem a palavra handle servem justamente para passar os cookies através das requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiosamente, consegui resolver o problema simplificando o código do `httr`. Parece que o pacote recebeu uma atualização e agora recebe um parâmetro `encode`, que pode receber `multipart` (padrão), `form` (o que eu quero fazer) e `json`.

Além disso, o `httr` já guarda por padrão os cookies entre seções. O código abaixo funcionou

```
library(httr)
link <- "http://siteempresas.bovespa.com.br/consbov/ExibeTodosDocumentosCVM.asp?CNPJ=02.541.982/0001-54&CCVM=22551&TipoDoc=C&QtLinks=10"
aux <- GET(link)
dados=list(hdnCategoria='0', hdnPagina='', FechaI='', FechaV='')
r1 <- POST(link, body=dados, encode='form')
cat(content(r1, 'text'))
```